# Circuit breaker config not working properly

Tags: molecule, moleculer

I am setting up new molecular project and trying to config circuit breaker in my project under molecular.config.js and set windowOpen to 6 sec. But when i do any operation and throw an error. Circuit doesn't break down. I am not able to find any solution for this.

Need Help

Answer (score 0):

Here you can see the parameters: https://moleculer.services/docs/0.13/fault-tolerance.html#Settings

The default values don't trip the CB after the first error. E.g. the number of requests should reach the `minRequestCount`. If you want to trip the CB after the first error, set  `threshold: 1` & `minRequestCount: 0`

Comment: when i checked in module the status inside trip method in circuit-breaker.js, it shows me open but when i again call the service then it again passes which i need to block. 
I am not able to block the request at current service.